# Assigning return value of a function to a variable in Python

Tags: python

I have a function which calculate the max in a list:

```
def max_in_list(list):
    max = 0
    for i in range(len(list)-1):
        if list[i] > list [i+1] and list [i] > max:
            max = list[i]
        elif list[i +1] > max:
            max = list [i+1]

print max
```

another one to map the lenght of strings to a new list

```
def maps(list):
    list_integer = []
    for i in list:
        list_integer.append(len(i))

    print list_integer
```

and I want to calculate the longest word with this one:

```
def the_longest_word(list):

    new_list = maps(list)
    max_in_list(new_list)
```

It looks like the first function return None. My question is how can I assign the returned value to a variable so I can use it in the second function?

Comment: `max_in_list` doesn't return anything (`None` by default), it just modifies the *local* variable `max`.

Comment: You need to ***`return`*** something from the function in the first place...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of printing you need `return` result at end of function :

```
def max_in_list(list):
    max = 0
    for i in range(len(list)-1):
        if list[i] > list [i+1] and list [i] > max:
            max = list[i]
        elif list[i+1] > max:
            max = list [i+1]
    return max
```

and:

```
def maps(list):
    list_integer = []
    for i in list:
        list_integer.append(len(i))
    return list_integer
```

so the last function should be like this:

```
def the_longest_word(list):

    new_list = maps(list)
    return max_in_list(new_list)
```